# Count the frequency of a recurring list -- inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, counter

I have a list of lists in python and I need to find how many times each sub-list has occurred. Here is a sample,

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [[ 1., 4., 2.5], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], 
         [ 1., 2., 2.], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], [ 1., 4., 2.5],
         [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333]]   
c = Counter(x for x in iter(list1))
print c
```

I above code will work, if the elements of the list were hashable (say int), but in this case they are lists and I get an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I count these lists so I get something like

```
[ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], 3
[ 1., 4., 2.5], 2
[ 1., 2., 2.], 1
```

Comment: Convert them to tuples - they're hashable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just convert the lists to `tuple`:

```
>>> c = Counter(tuple(x) for x in iter(list1))
>>> c
Counter({(1.0, 2.66666667, 1.33333333): 3, (1.0, 4.0, 2.5): 2, (1.0, 2.0, 2.0): 1})
```

Remember to do the same for lookup:

```
>>> c[tuple(list1[0])]
2
```

Comment: Wow that is amazingly simple. Just to make sure that the counter always returns back the values in an order from highest  to lowest frequencies ?

Comment: @WanderingMind Not sure what you mean. If you want the items in order of descending frequency, use `c.most_common()`.

Comment: The result you showed had frequencies from high to low values. I wanted to know if that was the expected outcome. It seems, you need to use the `most_common()` to obtain that behavior.

Comment: @WanderingMind `Counter` is backed by a dictionary, so the order in which they are printed when you just print or iterate the counter is kind of random. If you want to get them in a certain order, you have to use `most_common`.

Comment: @tobias_k, Is there to print generator objects so that it does not append '<generator object [function].<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000027AC384A...>,' to the items in the tuple that it is pointing to?

Comment: @spacedustpi I don't understand. Where do you see that output? Did you do `Counter([(tuple(x) for x in list1)])`? That would be a list containing a single generator.

Comment: Sorry, that was ambiguous. I have these tuple pairs inside a tuple. One is a generator object (of a lemmatized sentence token), and the other is the original sentence. Wanted to see if I could use your code ('Counter') to count these pairs to get their frequencies, with a caveat. First turn the generator object into the actual sentence token. My current solution is to turn the generator object into a tuple first from within the function it come from. But I was wondering if there was a more efficient (faster) way, such as turning it into a tuple from within the Counter function.

Answer (score 2):

Counter returns a dictionary like object which it's keys must be hashable. And since lists are not hashable you can convert them to `tuple` using `map` function:

```
>>> Counter(map(tuple, list1))
Counter({(1.0, 2.66666667, 1.33333333): 3, (1.0, 4.0, 2.5): 2, (1.0, 2.0, 2.0): 1})
```

Note that using `map` will perform slightly better than a generator expression because by passing a generator expression to `Counter()` python will get the values from generator function by itself, since using built-in function `map` has more performance in terms of execution time<sup>1</sup>.

```
# Use generator expression
~ $ python -m timeit --setup "list1 = [[ 1., 4., 2.5], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333],[ 1., 2., 2.], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], [ 1., 4., 2.5],[ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333]] ;from collections import Counter" "Counter(tuple(x) for x in iter(list1))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.86 usec per loop
# Use map
~ $ python -m timeit --setup "list1 = [[ 1., 4., 2.5], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333],[ 1., 2., 2.], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], [ 1., 4., 2.5],[ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333]] ;from collections import Counter" "Counter(map(tuple, list1))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.92 usec per loop
```

From [PEP 0289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

> The semantics of a generator expression are equivalent to creating an anonymous generator function and calling it. For example:
>
> ```
> g = (x**2 for x in range(10))
> print g.next()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def __gen(exp):
>     for x in exp:
>         yield x**2
> g = __gen(iter(range(10)))
> print g.next()
> ```

---

<sub>Note that since *generator expressions* are better in terms of memory use, if you are dealing with large data you'd better use *generator expression* instead of *map* function.</sub>

Comment: Is there a similar pythonic way for lookup?

Comment: @WanderingMind What you mean by lookup?

Comment: How to know the frequency of a particular sublist say `list1[5]`

Comment: Just put the result of `map(tuple, list1)` in a new list then do `Counter_object[new_list[5]]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list1 = [[ 1., 4., 2.5], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], 
         [ 1., 2., 2.], [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333], [ 1., 4., 2.5],
         [ 1., 2.66666667, 1.33333333]]

counter = {}
for el in list1:
    el = str(el)     #This sorts your hashable part or use tuple(el)
    if el in counter:
        counter[el]+=1
    else:
        counter[el]=1

print(counter)
```

Should output

```
{'[1.0, 2.0, 2.0]': 1, '[1.0, 2.66666667, 1.33333333]': 3, '[1.0, 4.0, 2.5]': 2}
```